# Laravel route not defined error even though it is

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following blade code:

```
<a href="{{ route('settings') }}">
    <span class="title">Settings</span>
</a>
```

I have the following defined at the top of my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::post('settings/update', 'SettingsController@update');
Route::resource('settings', 'SettingsController');
```

When I try to go to any page with `route('settings')` I get a `Route [settings] not defined` error.

If I do `php artisan routes` I can see that the settings routes are all there as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `route('settings')` you refer to a route named `settings` but you don't have such a route. RESTful routes will automatically receive a route name though.

For the `index` method it is `resource.index` for the `show` method `resource.show` and so on.

Change your code to this:

```
<a href="{{ route('settings.index') }}">
    <span class="title">Settings</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change {{ route('settings') }} to {{ URL::to('settings') }}